# Angular 4: Select option with 'disabled' attribute is not selected by default when model value is empty

Tags: angular

When the model is empty, the selected/disabled option is not selected in Chrome/firefox. This works perfectly fine is Safari.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedProject" name="project" id="project">
   <option value="" [selected]=true [disabled]="true">Select project</option>
   <option [value]="project.id" *ngFor="let project of projects">{{project.title}}</option>
</select>
```

This was reported as a bug in AngularJS, however, neither [disabled] or disabled works for me.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7202

Comment: That's strange, I just tested, and it's the opposite: it's checked in chrome but not in Safari: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwjmzk?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me. i'm using chrome version Version 61.0.3163.79 btw

Comment: Mine is behind a little bit. By selected, you mean the 'tick', right?

Comment: Nope, the disabled option should be selected initially, not just checked.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have not selected in both browsers. Just in chrome, it's ticked. I used your snippet.

Comment: Okay, but the expect behaviour is that it should be selected if you just use plain html <select>

Comment: I don't know... It seems to me logical that if it's disabled, it cannot be selected. And just plain 'selected disabled ' work the same

Answer (score 1):

Surprised this wasn't answered still. Anyways this worked for me..

For disabling it

```
<select [attr.disabled]=true class="custom-select" formControlName="title">
     <option [value]="project.id" *ngFor="let project of projects">{{project.title}} 
     </option>
</select>
```

And For enabling it

```
<select [attr.disabled]=null class="custom-select" formControlName="title">
     <option [value]="project.id" *ngFor="let project of projects">{{project.title}} 
     </option>
</select>
```

You can also set variable to it. Works like a charm!