# Angular2: Set placeholder for select

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a select dropdown like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.department" name="dept">

  <option *ngFor="let dept of departmentList" [ngValue]="dept">{{dept}}</option>
</select>
```

While adding a student it should show the placeholder as "Select Dept" and while editing student it should show the selected value.
I tried adding

```
<option value="" disabled="true" [selected]="true">--please select--</option>
```

But its not getting selected by default.

Comment: Is this the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46098780/5468463

Comment: https://netbasal.com/angular-quick-tip-how-to-show-a-placeholder-in-select-control-bab688f98b98

Answer (score 3):

You could set the default value of the `<select>` by setting the value of `studentObj.department` to match the empty string (`''`) value of the default `<option>`:

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  studentObj: { [key: string]: any } = {
    department: ''
  };

  departmentList: string[] = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'foobar'
  ];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" [(ngModel)]="studentObj.department" name="dept">
  <option value="" disabled="true">--please select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let dept of departmentList" [ngValue]="dept">{{dept}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7e39pk?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) showing this functionality in action. This would effectively work well with Reactive Forms as well as you'd initialize a default value when creating the `FormControl` elements. This approach works with standard cross-browser `<select>`/`<option>` elements without dependencies on 3rd party libraries.

**Note:** You may not really need `ngValue` if your `departmentList` is just an array of strings. `ngValue` would only really be needed if each department in `departmentList` is an object. If it is an object, you may need to target a specific property on the `dept` placeholder variable within `*ngFor` for the display text of each .

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder is simple, I use Angular2 material,
so it like this:

```
         <md-select placeholder="--please select--">
             <md-option *ngFor="let dept of departmentList" [ngValue]="dept">{{dept}} </md-option>
        </md-select>
```

it works as expected.

Comment: Use Angular2 material, if you didn't install it, please run npm i --save @angular/material @angular/cdk hammerjs first, then  
In the module or component file, you need import MaterialModule of Angular2 material. import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

Answer (score 0):

This is how i implemented ,

```
initializeSelectOptions(){
 this.optionList = ['..' , '..' , '..'
  ];
 this.optionList.unshift('Select Options')
}

ngOnInit(){
 this.initializeSelectOptions();
}
```

in the template :

```
<select class='select-option' required [(ngModel)]='optionSelected' (ngModelChange)='optionChanged($event)'>
    <option class='option' *ngFor='let option of optionList' [value]="option " [disabled]="option === 'Select Options'">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```